# Maximum Size of characters in Page Name in CQ5

Tags: aem

when we are creating a page using Scaffolding it is only taking page name maximum 20 characters,is there any other way to override that validation? Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

In the default scaffolding, (/libs/wcm/scaffolding/components/scaffolding/body.jsp) on line 242 you see the following code:

```
var title = frm.findField("./jcr:content/jcr:title");
if (title) {
    var hint = title.getValue();
    if (hint) {
        params[":nameHint"] = hint;
    }
}
```

The main thing to take away from this code is params[":nameHint"].  This param is submitted when you create a page.  The nameHint paramater is what causes the node name to be limited to x amount of characters.  When nameHint is submitted, it runs through a filter which formats the name for JCR.  This is done to ensure a valid JCR name.  It is for your protection.  You can read more about this in the **Algorithm for Node Name Creation** section on this page: http://sling.apache.org/site/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servletspost.html

To overwrite this problem, you would need to change params[":nameHint"] to params[":name"]. Just remember, that this won't ensure a valid JCR name.  If this is a concern, you can always right some code to change the title to a valid JCR name and then set it to the :name param.

One other thing, I did read this - "when :nameHint is filtered it cuts the name to a **configurable** maximum length (default is 20 characters)".  I cannot find how this is configured though.

Answer (score -1):

Configure CQ POST servlet.. and you should be good